# Using multiple scanners to read file line by line resulting in noSuchElementException

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am not sure while am receiving a no such element exception. It seems to be an issue with the scanner not reading my file correctly, but I am not sure where I am going wrong.

I am reading a file, then using the scanner to go line by line. But I get unusual behavior, such as missing lines or filenotfound exceptions when I try to do it.

```
    public static void readMylifeLikeABook(String fileName,int maxItems) {
        // Read file line by line with different elements on each line
        int bookCount=0;
        int movieCount = 0;
        Book [] bookItem =new Book[maxItems];
        Movie [] movieItem =new Movie[maxItems];

        try {
            File file = new File(fileName);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            Scanner line;
            while (scanner.hasNext() && ((bookCount+movieCount)<maxItems)) {
                line = new Scanner(scanner.nextLine()); // scan next line
                if (line.next().contains("Movie")){
                    movieItem[movieCount]= new Movie();
                    movieItem[movieCount].setMediaType("Movie");
                    movieItem[movieCount].setTitle(scanner.nextLine());
                    movieItem[movieCount].setRef(scanner.nextLine());
                    movieItem[movieCount].setPrice(Double.valueOf(scanner.nextLine()));
                    movieItem[movieCount].setDirector(scanner.nextLine());
                    movieItem[movieCount].setActor(scanner.nextLine());
                    System.out.println(movieItem[movieCount].getTitle());
                    movieCount++;
                    line.close();                           // close line
                }
                else if (scanner.next().contains("Book")){
                    bookItem[bookCount]= new Book();
                    bookItem[bookCount].setMediaType("Book");
                    bookItem[bookCount].setTitle(scanner.nextLine());
                    bookItem[bookCount].setRef(scanner.nextLine());
                    bookItem[bookCount].setPrice(Double.valueOf(scanner.nextLine()));
                    bookItem[bookCount].setAuthor(scanner.nextLine());
                    System.out.println(bookItem[bookCount].getTitle());
                    bookCount++;
                    line.close();                           // close line
                }
            }
            scanner.close();
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //System.out.println(count);
        for (int i=0;i<(bookCount+movieCount);i++) {
            System.out.println(bookItem[i] +"\n\n "+ movieItem[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sample file  being read;

Movie
2001: A Space Odyssey
TU2RL012
11.99
Stanley Kubrick
Keir Dullea

Book
Data Structure and Algorithms
UI7P3J6Y
32.49
Robert Lafore

Movie
Stars Wars: Episode IV
R2D2C3P0
13.83
Georges Lucas
Mark Hamill

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, is it possible if you can provide the file being read? This can very well be a problem with that File as if the Scanner object does not a following line to be read, it will throw an exception. Make sure the file has the needed amount of lines.

Answer (score 0):

You call `line.next()` immediately after constructing `line`. Do you need to do this? If so, perhaps you need to call `hasNext()` first to ensure there's a token there.

(I'm pretty sure `line.next()` throws a `NoSuchElementException` if there's no token.)

Also, check your code against the file format. Are there blank lines in your file?